# Как в django избежать зависания на функции mail.send_mail

Tags: python, django

Когда я пользуюсь функцией send_mail() из djanog.core.mail, приложение останавливается и ожидает пока ответит указанный сервер почты. Мне это не нравиться и я могу позволить себе не ждать результатов выполнения.

```
def index(request):
    send_mail('subj','mes','from@mail.com',[request.GET.get('email_to')])
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

Как мне избежать зависания на функции send_mail?

Comment: Начиная с версии 3.5 в питоне доступна конструкция async/await для неблокирующих операций ввода-вывода https://stackabuse.com/python-async-await-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Короткий ответ: в теории то что Вы хотите возможно, но есть более правильный вариант.

---

## Наиболее верный вариант.

Django синхронный framework. Для того что бы выполнять почтовые рассылки вы должны использовать очередь (RabbitMQ или аналоги) которая гарантирует сохранность события и smtp сервер для отправки письма.

## Threading.

В питоне есть модуль для многопоточного программирования. В теории через него Вы сможете отправлять письма без задержек. Но это довольно опасная дорога, ведь при больших нагрузках на вашем сервере будут создаваться **новые потоки для каждого отправления**, к тому же в случае аварийного выключения сервера, вы потеряете всю очередь отправки писем.